# Give profile location data a hyperlink to open a map

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, location

On the right-hand side of the "Profile" tab of the user profile page is the user's location data (if any), with a "map pin" icon. But it is not an active hyperlink.

Can we make the location data a link, so that it opens a map showing where the pin is when clicked?

I would suggest using google maps, something like  `https://www.google.com/maps/search/<user-location>`, for example https://www.google.com/maps/search/Paris,+France, but that's up to the implementation.

This seems like it would require small dev effort, but would be cool IMHO.

Comment: The field is free-form and not validated. People can (and do) put in any old thing there.

Comment: @Oded What's the downside of just linking anyway?

Comment: What is the upside besides, 'oeh, watch this link!'? I understand your request, but I don't feel anything for it.

Comment: @Patrick I clicked one and expected it to work. I was surprised it didn't work. That's what prompted this question.

Comment: So [this user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/196157/electronerd) will appear to live in [United Nations Office for Outer Space Affairs](https://www.google.com/maps/search/Outer+Space)?

Comment: The downsides? Malicious links, link rot, links that don't go anywhere.

Comment: @Shadow So what? That's the expected result if I click a map link to "Outer Space"! Most people enter sensible data (if any) anyway.

Comment: @Oded malicious links is a good point. Good enough that to do the idea would probably require "safe" lat/long from the user (which I think would be interesting data, but not worth the effort)

Comment: @Bohemian in most (or at least a lot of) cases it *still* wouldn't work, which would lead to even more confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't think this is necessary. Apart of what Oded said in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284837/give-profile-location-data-a-hyperlink-to-open-a-map#comment923728_284837) that the data is not validated and users can put whatever they like (e.g. Outer Space, Your Mind, etc.), what you want is two clicks away, with Chrome browser at least:

1. Select the location:

   > [image]
2. Right click and choose "Search Google for...":

   > [image]
3. Click the "Maps tab:

   > [image]